# Petición Post con parámetros con corchetes como key

Tags: javascript, nodejs, axios

Necesito hacer una petición POST a una API REST. Desde postman no tengo ningún problema. El problema viene cuando desde el código intentó pasarle los dos parámetros a la peticion. Estos parámetros tienen un formato algo raros `user[login]` y `user[password]`, cuando intento pasarlo con comillas simples, dobles, da error ya que llega un string y no el nombre del campo.

Mi petición estoy utilizando NodeJS y Axios como libreria para las peticiones.

```
const postToken = async() => {
    var params = { "user[login]": "xxxxx", "user[password]": "x" };
    try {
        await axios.post('https://decidecrop.nazaries.cloud/public_api/v1/users/sign_in', params, {
            headers: { "accept": "application/json", "Content-Type": "application/json" }
        })
    } catch (error) {
        console.error(error)
        throw error
    }
}
```

Como puedo poner de tal forma que `user[login]` y `user[password]` seas dos campos?

Esta es el API DOC

```
https://decidecrop.nazaries.cloud/public_api/v1/apidocs
```

Gracias un saludo

Comment: ¿Quieres poner el valor de user[login] como key del objeto ? Segun lo que entendi

Comment: El API usa formdata, pero puedes probar con `{user: {login: "xxx", password: "xxx"}`

Comment: Si, justamente quiero poner el key como el valor

Comment: ¿Y si pruebas a usar `'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'` como header? Tambien echale un vistazo a esto: https://github.com/axios/axios/issues/1640

Comment: He anteriormente con application/x-www-form-urlencoded así es como lo tengo en Postman, pero aquí sigue pasando lo mismo el error que me devuelve: { status: 'unprocessable_entity',
        error: 'You must provide user[login] and user[password] params' } } }

Comment: @PabloLozano he probado y tampoco funciona

Comment: @Manolait desde mi punto de vista, el que tengas que recibir en el API Rest, un parametro llamado 'user[login]', no me parece lo mas adecuado. Deberias de permitir 2 parametros separados: login y password, o un objeto user, que a su vez contenga 2 parametros: login y password.

Comment: Hola, yo opino igual, pero es una API de una empresa y tengo que adaptarme a su formato....sigo sin poder y llevo toda la tarde

Answer (score 0):

Por lo que estoy viendo en la API, creo que tienes que mandar los datos en formato que concuerde con `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`: usando un objeto [`FormData`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/FormData):

```
const data = new FormData();
data.append('user[name]','xxxx');
data.append('user[password]','xxxx');
axios.post(url,data, ...);
```

El problema es que axios no trabaja con FormData *nativo* en Node, pero se puede resolver usando una [librería externa](https://www.npmjs.com/package/form-data):

```
const FormData = require('form-data');
```

Comment: Hola Pablo, estoy probando y no funciona, he instalado la librería que has comentado y el error es el siguiente: cannot read property 'data' of undefined

Answer (score 0):

Al final la solución fue la siguiente:

```
const postToken = async() => {
    var params = {
        user: {
            login: 'xxxx',
            password: 'xxxx'
        }
    }
    try {
        return await axios.post('https://decidecrop.nazaries.cloud/public_api/v1/users/sign_in', params, {
            headers: { "accept": "application/json", "Content-Type": "application/json" }
        })
    } catch (error) {
        //console.error(error)
        throw error
    }
}
```

Gracias por la ayuda.